# JavaScript .replace() part of a url not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, href, attr

running into a little issue, can't quite figure it out. I'm using jQuery on a page to handle some image loading and lightboxing. Part of the feature set requires replacing a portion of an anchor tags `href` to direct it towards a different resource.

there are a variable amount of images in the set, so I'm using jQuery's `.each()` method to grab them, replace part of the url, then fade them in one after the order. The fading works correctly, but JavaScript's `.replace()` isn't taking effect (though if i turn them into a variable and log it i see the correct results) and if i chain the fade in function to the back of `.replace` it doesn't get executed.

feels like the value isn't being returned to the elements. what am i missing?

thanks for your help!

HTML:

```
<a class="test" href="aresourcewithextension_b.jpg">
    <img src="aresourcewithextension_a.jpg" />
</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.test').each(function(i){
    $(this).attr('href').replace('_b.jpg','_c.jpg').delay(100*i).animate({opacity:1},200);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the replaced href. `.replace` itself won't update the original string.

Try like below,

```
this.href = this.href.replace('_b.jpg','_c.jpg');
```

Comment: ah, thought so. you win!

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that strings are immutable, even in JavaScript. Try this:

```
$(".test").each(function(i){
    $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href").replace("_b.jpg", "_c.jpg"));
    $(this).delay(100 * i).animate({opacity:1}, 200);
});
```